# Comparing Two lists of Different Objects without for loop

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have two lists:

```
List<ObjA> AList;
List<ObjB> BList;
```

Now I have a method to compare individual `Obj A` to `Obj B`:

```
void CompareObjAToObjB(ObjA a, ObjB b)
{
   ....
}
```

where it asserts the individual elements of objects by comparing them. For now, I did by sorting the two lists using an unique identifier and then iterate the sorted list through a `for` loop and calling the `Compare` method.

Is there a better way to compare the lists using a Lambda expression or Linq?

```
Edit
```

ok. Here is My original code..

```
 Alist.sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x.acctNumber, y.acctNumber));
 Blist.sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x.acctNumber, y.acctNumber));

 for(int i =0; i< Alist.count; i++)
 {
      CompareObjAToObjB(Alist[i], Blist[i]);
 }
```

Alist contains the repo Object that I input where as BList is a Object that returns by a Service API call. Both contains the same data but in different structures.

Comment: What do you want to do with this comparison?

Comment: How “better”? Show your original, working code and tell us your *specific* concerns.

Comment: Note that most of the LINQ methods use a for loop inside.

Comment: (and don't repeat tags in question titles, please)

Comment: Your `CompareObjAToObjB` doesn't actually return anything so what would you expect the result to be? What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: as @OndrejJanacek says, if your doing this to improve performance, it's unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: What is the relationship between `ObjA` and 'ObjB` types? You cannot compare unrelated things, like horses and apples.

Comment: Ondrej janacek, I know Linq uses for loop each. The improvement is just from 'shortening' perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to find all items with the same identifier you could use `Join`:

```
var inBoth = from a in AList
             join b in BList
             on a.UniqueIdentifier equals b.UniqueIdentifier 
             select new { a, b };

foreach(var ab in inBoth)
    Console.WriteLine("A:{0} B:{1}", a.ToString(), b.ToString()); // if ObjA  and ObjB have a meaningful ToString
```

Comment: what if Blist is an integer list of uniqueidentifier and not a class?

Comment: yeah figured out it wasnt working because there was no data returned from the database :D